# Сайт работает на локалхосте, а из Инетрнета он не открывается

Tags: lamp, ubuntu, apache2

Установил Убунту 13.10, поднял LAMP. Если захожу в браузере на localhost, то сайт открывается без проблем... У меня внешний IP. Но в браузере я не могу зайти на свой внешний ИП, не на адрес сайта. Что я сделал не так?

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAMEfirefox 2470  travian   73u  IPv4  36220      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:40466->web01.vesti3.vesti.cc.colocall.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)firefox 2470  travian   74u  IPv4  36221      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:40467->web01.vesti3.vesti.cc.colocall.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)firefox 2470  travian   76u  IPv4  31950      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:60069->194.247.175.35:http (CLOSE_WAIT)firefox 2470  travian   77u  IPv4  35646      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:58371->192.168.88.1:http (SYN_SENT)firefox 2470  travian   82u  IPv4  31951      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:60070->194.247.175.35:http (CLOSE_WAIT)firefox 2470  travian   87u  IPv4  35628      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:60595->194.247.175.35:http (CLOSE_WAIT)firefox 2470  travian   90u  IPv4  35629      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:60596->194.247.175.35:http (CLOSE_WAIT)firefox 2470  travian   94u  IPv4  35647      0t0  TCP ubuntu.local:58372->192.168.88.1:http (SYN_SENT)apache2 4159     root    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4163 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4164 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4165 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4167 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4264 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4266 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4273 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4274 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4275 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)apache2 4276 www-data    4u  IPv6  37013      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что у вас указано в директиве [listen][1].  [1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Comment: listen 80 указано

Comment: sudo lsof -i TCP:80что показывает?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос то, что вывела эта команда..

Comment: у вас апач слушает только ipv6-адрес.Попробуйте указать Listen 0.0.0.0:80 вместо listen 80.

Comment: Так и указывать 0.0.0.0 или 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Прописал 127.0.0.1:80, ребутнул Апач, теперь он слушает ipv4-адрес. Но зайти на сайт из Интернета по прежднему не получается...

Answer (score 1):

1. Что работает шлюзом у сети с хостом с LAMPой? [Порт пробросить](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) не пробовали? Смысл: приходит запрос на внешний IP -> ему говорят "не знаю чо с тобой делать, иди отсюда". Так вот надо рассказать *всем* устройствам, через которые в вашу сеть попадает тырнет, **что** делать, если приходит запрос на порт 80. Например: есть модем с ADSL + шлюзовая машинка  -> на модеме настраиваете пересылку на шлюз, на шлюзе - на хост с LAMPой. И все :)
2. Какой внешний IP - статика или динамический? Если статика и зарегистрируете свой домен - то сможете ходить не только по внешнему IP.

---

UP

На самом деле, подобный вопрос уже был. [ПОЧИТАТЬ](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/3041/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5).

Comment: 1. Уже все проброшено, стоял сервер, все работало, решили его заменить.. Пока идет замена я поставил Убунту на ноутбук, поставил Апач, Мускул и ПХП. И подключил к сети вместо сервера, но тут произошел облом. Ничего не заработало...2. Внешний ИП статический, он постоянный + уже привязан к домену.

Comment: Проброс перенастроили на новый IP?

Comment: нет, не могу зайти на роутер.

Comment: Как вариант - дать ноуту тот же ip , что был у сервера (тот, на который был проброс).

Answer (score 0):

Listen 0.0.0.0:80 - будет слушать все доступные ipv4 адреса.Listen 127.0.0.1:80 - только локалхост.Поэтому вам нужен первый вариант.

Comment: Прописал Listen 0.0.0.0:80, но сайт не заработал из Интернета(((

Comment: у вас внешний ip вообще поднят на ноуте?Какой у вас вывод ifconfig?После прописывания Listen 0.0.0.0:80 покажите вывод lsof -i TCP:80?